# Dispelling Haste with Slow

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

[Haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) and [Slow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow) are opposites of each other.

Our group got attacked by creatures under the same haste spell. Our caster responded by casting slow on them but due to their spreading out was unable to hit all the ones under the effects of haste, and also hit some that were not under the effect of haste.

Slow

> Slow counters and dispels haste.

Haste

> Haste dispels and counters slow.

We were unclear on exactly what happens. We came up with the following potential cases and were not sure which was correct

- The whole haste spell is dispelled and no other effect
- Haste is dispelled and others can be affected by slow
- Only the ones within the slow area are dispelled of haste or slowed

There is a related [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45306/23058) which was dispel magic and multiple summons from the same spell.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69243/8610)

Comment: I don't think it is because this one specifically relates to individual targets of areas. Very related though.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Was not a duplicate but that does directly answer the question I asked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qjy) the *Pathfinder Core Rulebook FAQ* directly addresses this issue:

> *Dispel Example:* You are a 5th-level wizard, your opponent is a 6th-level sorcerer. On her turn, the sorcerer casts *slow* and targets 6 of your allies; all 6 of them fail their saves and are *slowed*. On your turn, you cast *haste* and target 5 of your allies; this automatically dispels (no caster level check needed) the *slow* spell on those allies, leaving them without the effect of *slow* or *haste* (your 6th ally is still affected by *slow*). Note that this does not merely suppress the *slow* effect for the duration of your *haste*—the effect is completely dispelled on those 5 allies. Note that it doesn't matter if the target would normally get a saving throw or spell resistance to negate or avoid the spell used to dispel (such as casting *slow* to dispel an already-caste *haste*); to speed up gameplay and prevent lopsided applications of this sort of dispelling, the "diametrically opposed" spell automatically dispels its opposite, regardless of the desires of the creature affected by the opposite.

Thus, in your case, after picking the targets of the [*slow*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spell, those folks who were affected by the [*haste*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) spell automatically wouldn't be affected by the *haste* spell any longer and also wouldn't be affected by the *slow* spell, but those folks who weren't affected by the *haste* spell would make saving throws against the *slow* spell normally.